# Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Tags: javascript, python, django, json, serialization

I get an error when sending JSON data to JavaScript from the models. It looks like encoding is causing the error, but all the examples I have found work for other people. How can I properly send model data from my view to JavaScript?

view code:

```
def home(request):
  import json
  info_obj = Info.objects.all()
  json_data = serializers.serialize("json", info_obj)
  return render_to_response("pique/home.html", {'json_data':json_data}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

JavaScript code:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{{json_data}}');
console.log(data);
```

The error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('[{&quot;pk&quot;: 1, &quot;model&quot;: &quot;pique.eat&quot; ...
```

Comment: Additionally to the answers below: Have a look at Django Braces. There, the json view is already implemented
http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/other.html#jsonrequestresponsemixin

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must use `"` instead of `&quot;` in the string.

The string was automatically escaped by `render_to_response`.

To avoid this you must mark `json_data` safe. Use `mark_safe` for it.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
return render_to_response(
  "pique/home.html",
  {
     'json_data':mark_safe(json_data)
  },
  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar issue and this helped me solve mine too !

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is html encoded. It should come from the server with quotes and all. Is `render_to_response` doing some sort of encoding? What does `json_data` look like before that function?